# Hosting multiple Single Page Apps with Docker

Tags: docker, webserver, single-page-application

We have a couple of single page apps that we want to host on a single web server. I'm only talking about the frontend part (Angular, React). The APIs run elsewhere. Each app is basically just a directory with a collection of static files (js, html, css, etc.) generated by the CI process. In fact, the build process creates one Docker image per app. Each image basically just contains a directory that contains the build artifacts.

All apps should appear in different folders on the same website:

```
/app1
/app2
/app3
```

What would be the best practice for deploying the apps? We've come up with a few strategies.

### 1. A single image / container

We could build a final web server image (e.g. Apache) and merge all the directories from the app images into it.

Cons: Versioning sounds like hell. Each new version of an app causes a new version of the final image. What if we want to revert to an older version of an app while a newer version of another app has already been deployed?

### 2. Multiple containers with a front-end reverse proxy

We could build each app image with its own built-in web server. And then route them all together with a front-end reverse proxy (nginx, traefik, etc.).

Cons: Waste of resources running multiple web servers.

### 3. One web server container and multiple data-only containers for the apps

Deploy each app in a separate container that provides it's app directory as a volume but does nothing else. Then there is a separate web server container that shares the same volumes in order to have access to all the files.

---

So far I like the 3rd variant best. Whenever a new version of an app needs to be deployed, we simply do a Docker pull on a new version of its image. But it still seems hacky. Volumes must be deleted manually. Otherwise the volume will not be seeded with the new content. Also having containers that do nothing isn't the Docker way, isn't it?

Comment: Is it deployed anywhere in the cloud? What about a single nginx with exposed volume with contexts (and possibly a config). Deployment would be simply replacing files in a context. I mean... Docker for SPAs is usually quite an overkill, I wouldn't put all websites into one container that's for sure. If you want to use docker and separate those apps, I'd use nginx alpine per app in docker and another nginx for reverse-proxy. That's of course if you don't need some more fancy reverse-proxying functionalities.

Answer (score 1):

A Docker container wraps a *process*, but your compiled front-end applications are *static files*.  That is, the setup you're describing here doesn't really match Docker's model.

Without Docker you could imagine deploying these to a single directory

```
/var/www/
  app1/
    index.html
    css/app.css
  app2/
    index.html
    css/app2.css
    js/main.js
```

and serve these with a single HTTP server; you would not typically run a separate server for each front-end application.

A totally reasonable option, in fact, is to completely ignore Docker here.  Even if your back-end applications are being served from containers, you can publish your front-end code (again, compiled to static files) via whatever hosting service you have conveniently available.  Things like Webpack's file hashing can help support deploying updated versions of the application without breaking existing clients.

If I was using Docker I'd use either of your first two options but not the third.  Running a combined all-the-front-ends HTTP server is the same pattern already discussed, except the HTTP server is in a container instead of the host.  Running a dedicated HTTP server for each front-end application lets you use Docker's image versioning, and the incremental cost of an additional HTTP server isn't that expensive.

I would avoid any approach that involves named volumes or "data-only containers".  Nothing ever automatically copies content into a volume, except for one specific corner case (on native Docker only, using named volumes but not any other kind of mount, only the first time you use a volume but never updating the volume content), and so you'd have to manually write code to copy content out of an image into a shared hosting location; that's more complicated and doesn't really gain you anything over directly running Webpack on the host.

Comment: I just wanted to come back and give some feedback after we have deployed the system for quite some time now and have more experience. You gave sound advice. We opted for option 2. The overhead is not that bad and the flexibility is great. Updating or moving an app to a different server is a matter of seconds. It turned out that a separate reverse proxy is needed anyway. Traefik does an awesome job handling SSL and other things.